# Adding a control to the main container of unknown object

Tags: c#, wpf

```
void Visualize(object CoreObj, object ParentControl)
{
    if(CoreObj is typeA)
    {
        object control1 = new MyControl1(CoreObj);
        ParentControl.FirstChild.Children.Add(control1);
        foreach (object obj in CoreObj.Children)
        {
            Visualize(obj, control1);
        }
    }
    else if (CoreObj is typeB)
    {
        object control2 = new MyControl2(CoreObj);
        ParentControl.FirstChild.Children.Add(control2);
        foreach (object obj in CoreObj.Children)
        {
            Visualize(obj, control2);
        }
    }
}
```

Where FirstChild is always container, no matter StackPanel, Grid or Canvas, or whatever.
How I get the first child, and the harder part, how to do Children.Add() on object?

I can require something else in case "Children" is inherited from somewhere in all wpf containers, but I can't find out which ancestor/interface contains "Children". Or I can use Reflection probably..

How to do this?

Here's what I came with, finally

```
interface IContain
{
    Panel GetMain();  //return main container
}

// ...

void Visualize(object CoreObj, Panel ParentControl)
{
    UIElement control = new UIElement();

    if (CoreObj is File)                { control = new NameSpacer(); }      //new NameSpacer(obj);
    else if (CoreObj is Namespace)      { control = new NameSpacer(); }
    else if(CoreObj is Using)           { control = new NameSpacer(); }

                                                                        if (control.GetType() == typeof(UIElement)) return;
    ParentControl.Children.Add(control);



    FieldInfo finf = CoreObj.GetType().GetField("Children");            if (finf == null) return;
    var val = finf.GetValue(CoreObj);                                   if (val.GetType() != typeof(IEnumerable<object>)) return;
                                                                        if (control is IContain == false) return;

    Panel container = ((IContain)control).GetMain();
    foreach (object o in val as IEnumerable<object>)
    {
        Visualize(o, container);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use VisualTreeHelper class to get the first child.
2. Children property is defined in abstract class Panel.

```
var firstChild = parentControl.Descendants().OfType<Panel>().First();
firstChild.Children.Add(control1);
```

The descendants method leverages VisualTreeHelper in order to get all descendants and you have to define it as extension method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendants(this DependencyObject element)
    {
        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);

        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var visualChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);

            yield return visualChild;

            foreach (var visualChildren in Descendants(visualChild))
            {
                yield return visualChildren;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Answer (score 0):

StackPanel, Grid and Canvas, all derive from the Panel class. This is also the class that contains the Children property.

if you know your argument is a Panel, you also have access to Children.First() and Children.Add(..)